# Windows Universal Platform

Tags: win-universal-app

I am new to WUP and researching on Windows Universal platform, I have following questions for the same:
1)I would like to know if anyone has used it, and if it can be deployed anywhere else other than the windows store. How can we make the app available to the users/client without deploying it on the Windows store. (where else can we deploy the app?)
2) Will the app developed using WUP only works on Windows 10 or previous version of windows as well?
3) Can it be developed using 2015 or 2017 is mandatory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These questions would be more appropriate for the respective Windows forums. They don't seem to relate to a specific programming problem as per the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)How can we make the app available to the users/client without deploying it on the Windows store. (where else can we deploy the app?)

> Typically, you download these apps from the Store and that is how they are installed on your device. But you can sideload apps to your device without submitting them to the Store. This lets you install them and test them out using the app package (.appx) that you have created.

For more info, please refer [Sideload your app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package).

We can also use the App Installer, it is a Universal Windows App that is pre-installed as part of the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. The app enables a user to double-click any .appx or .appxbundle for easy installation, eliminating the need to run PowerShell or specialized scripts.

Please refer the [App Installer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2016/05/27/app-installer/).

> 2) Will the app developed using WUP only works on Windows 10 or previous version of windows as well?

Windows 10 apps can only run on Windows 10 (and newer). If you want to target 8.1, you have to build a Windows 8.1 app. A Windows 8.1 app should run on Windows 10 without any problems.

You can refer the [Develop apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx#Requirements), it lists the requirements of UWP apps.

> 3) Can it be developed using 2015 or 2017 is mandatory?

Yes, we can use the VS 2015 or the VS 2017 to develop the UWP apps.

Please refer the document of [Build UWP apps with Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx).